# How to join two String array in Java - Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

i m new in android, i m working in app which i need to add to Array. What i need  that will look like this

```html
String[] quest = {"first","Second","thrid"};
String[] Answer = {"Answer1","Answer2","Answer3","Answer4"};
```

And Result should contained the **First INDEX of Question Array and all the Value of second Array **
Please check the image i drawn for Result
[image]

without this , i can not go further in my app, if you know how to do so ,Please give your suggestion

i will  be very greatefull if you suggest solutions

thanks

Comment: Did you tried using Map? Link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html.

Comment: What do you mean 3rd array's all element. Do you have a 2-dimensional array? An ideal solution would have been keeping a two dimensional array for the arrays and another map where you can assign the element of the first array to the desire array as per the logic.

Comment: yes, but it did not work and i need two different array, looking to url that suggest

Comment: third array i meant that a new String Array that have new Values, i will try your suggestion  and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're developing some kind of "quiz" application, so I'd recommend using a class to keep track of all your entries.

A very simple barebones example of this could be:

```
class QuizEntry
{
    private final String question;
    private final String[] answers;

    public QuizEntry(String question, String[] answers)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
    }
}
```

You could then keep track of all your quiz' entries by having a collection (e.g. an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) with objects of QuizEntry.
Looping through the arrays would be a way to populate said collection.

```
List<QuizEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

for (String question : quest)
{
    entries.add(new QuizEntry(question, answers));
}
```

If you don't like the idea of defining a seperate class just to keep an entry's question and possible answers, you can consider using a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and using it in a similar manner as suggested above.

Comment: i m also thinking about to craete a new class that can hold all the Entries and we can use that entries ,i try to use and let you know

Comment: That does seem like the better idea; note that this would also allow you to specify the correct answer, so you could have a simple method to verify whether the user's input is correct. Furthermore, it'd be a breeze to override toString() to present the QuizEntry in an appealing format without much hassle.

Comment: Question : what is **quest** in for loop ?

Comment: can u please give any Reference of program or webiste that have example like this

Comment: I was referring to the "quest" array you declared as shown in your post. The for keyword indicates a loop, and this one iterates through every string in the quest array: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

HashMap array2 = new HashMap();
...
String answers[] = {"ans1", "ans2", "ans3", "ans4"};
array2.put("First", answers);

Comment: HashMap<String, String[]> array2 = new HashMap<String, String[]>();